# Codeigniter Create Thumbnail Not Working?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, thumbnails

I have 2 codeigniter functions for image upload and thumb creation.The Image upload function is working properly but creating thumb function is not working.
I don't Know What is the Mistake in my function?

```
function uploaded() //upload  function
{           
            $config['upload_path'] ='./uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] ='jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|JPEG|JPG|PNG|GIF|BMP|doc|docx|xlsx|txt';
            $config['max_size'] = $this->config->item('max_upload_size');
            $filename = strtolower($this->friendly($_FILES['image']['name']));
            $config['file_name'] = $filename;
            $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('image'))
            {
            $this->data['file'] = $this->upload->data(); 
            $this->thumb($filename);
            return true; 
            }

}
```

create thumb function

```
function thumb($filename)
{

$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = './uploads/'.$filename.'.jpg';
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width']    = 75;
$config['height']   = 50;
$config['new_image'] = './uploads/thumb/'.$filename;
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
}
```

Comment: i tried not working..

Comment: What is the path of uploads folder from the root

Comment: There are a few reasons why this could be happening. Firstly, change `$this->image_lib->resize();` to `if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) { die($this->image_lib->display_errors());}`. This will show you if there any standard errors. Please let me know what the error is (if there is one).  If there isn't one please could you let me know what OS you are using.

Comment: i got my answer.. what i wrong is, the file name send to the thumb function doesnt have the file extension.and some file name has whitespaces in names.. i clear it now.,

Comment: You should add your own answer

Answer (score 0):

little bit modification in your code.

Upload Function changes.

```
function uploaded() //upload  function
{           
            $config['upload_path'] ='./uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] ='jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|JPEG|JPG|PNG|GIF|BMP|doc|docx|xlsx|txt';
            $config['max_size'] = $this->config->item('max_upload_size');
            //$filename = strtolower($this->friendly($_FILES['image']['name'])); #your filename has been commented
            $filename = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]/', '_', $file_name); //replace special char including whitespace with _
            $filename = preg_replace('/_+/', '_', $file_name); //replace multiple _ with single one.
            $config['file_name'] = $filename;
            $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('image'))
            {
            $this->data['file'] = $this->upload->data(); 
            $this->thumb($filename);
            return true; 
            }

}
```

Thumb function changes.

```
function thumb($filename)
{

$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
//$config['source_image'] = './uploads/'.$filename.'.jpg';  #no need to make it static as you are allowing multiple extensions in allowed_types.
$config['source_image'] = './uploads/'.$filename;
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width']    = 75;
$config['height']   = 50;
$config['new_image'] = './uploads/thumb/'.$filename;
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
}
```